# How to generate a single MD5 hash out of a complete given table

Tags: sql, oracle, hash, md5

I'm new here. I tried to google for a simple answer but I don't seem to find any.
I've got Oracle RAC 19c with a DB up and running.

For testing purposes, I created a table in the following way in oracle SQL developer:

```
CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE big3 DATAFILE SIZE 3G AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE 3G
EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL UNIFORM SIZE 16M SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;
CREATE TABLE system.t_big3 TABLESPACE big3 PARALLEL 4 AS SELECT * FROM dba_source;
```

Here's the question: 
How can I generate a single MD5 hash for the given created table (all of it)?

I'd wish to make a very simple consistency check between production and backup site (i have Oracle RAC replicated to a backup site in realtime). I would assume a simple way can be - check DB in the backup site and ensure the table is not corrupted - by generating MD5 from the whole table in production and to do the same in backup site - and then compare the MD5 result string from the table from each site to ensure the backup is consistent.

Comment: How big are these tables - rows/columns/data type?  Why do you think a table can be "corrupted?"  You could add a column for the hash per row, and calculate with a trigger using STANDARD_HASH function.

Comment: Its a matter of a single table created above. The table should not be corrupted unless the replication to backup site is faulty that might corrupt things. That's why i just want to simply generate md5 hash from the table given in my question

Comment: read [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2053989900346972822)